# How to run a window resize function?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I run a "resize" JavaScript event in the following script. Basicially I like to do the following If I resize the window.

```
        classie.remove( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
        classie.remove( bodyEl, 'noscroll' );
        classie.remove( htmlEl, 'noscroll' );
```

Here is the full script:

https://jsfiddle.net/sz5rxw2a/

Comment: [Source documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize). Please, not that you are going to fire this event SEVERAL times in a single "resize"... I suggest setting a flag "beginresize" on this function, then another one to actually make any relevant change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest you do like this

By adjusting the preset timeout value, 66 (ms), you can choose how often the actual event should fire and execute your own custom functions.

```
(function(timeout) {     // make a local static var - timeout

  window.addEventListener("resize", function(e) {
    if ( !timeout ) {
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        timeout = null;
        actualResizeHandler(e);

        // Set the actual fire rate
      }, 66);
    }
  }, false);

  function actualResizeHandler(e) {
    // handle the resize event

    classie.remove( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
    classie.remove( bodyEl, 'noscroll' );
    classie.remove( htmlEl, 'noscroll' );

  }

}());
```

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not a good idea, but this would be your code

```
window.onresize = function(){
    classie.remove( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
    classie.remove( bodyEl, 'noscroll' );
    classie.remove( htmlEl, 'noscroll' );  
}
```

## Edit 1

It would be a good idea to look at using a [debouncing function](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function), to limit how often the function can fire. I'd recommend using the `addEventListener` function for these purposes, with the following configuration:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
}; 

var throttled_resize = debounce(function() {
    classie.remove( bodyEl, 'show-menu' );
    classie.remove( bodyEl, 'noscroll' );
    classie.remove( htmlEl, 'noscroll' );
}, 250);

window.addEventListener('resize', throttled_resize);
```

The latter is far more performant. Happy coding!